# How to pass attribute from angular.json file to typescript files

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am currently working on angular project, where I am able to switch between the environments by passing required parameter from the cli, where this environment configuration is made in angular.json file.

Now, what all I need is, parameter passing from cli to angular.json is correctly handled but I also want to use this parameter (from angular.json file) to my other typescript file.

How to read property from angular.json file to custom typescript file.?

Comment: how this file will be runing in ity part of the angular project ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want your application to be able to use a variable, the value of which depends on the environment configuration?

Comment: Define `fileReplacements` for some data.ts file in angular.json like it does for `src/environments/environment.ts` and import wherever you need it. Or just use `environment.ts` to store your data.